# How to store a displayed value mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to store `supName.compName` to a `variable` from the html file to typescript file additional to `supName.$key`

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select formControlName="supName" placeholder="Company">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let supName of array">
      <mat-option value="{{supName.$key}}">{{supName.compName}}</mat-option>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I'm new to angular

Comment: how about save the whole object?
or if you dont want to save the whole object use find() with the key you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a `formControlName` in your mat-form-field, it's safe to assume that you're using a Reactive Form.

So you'd have created a form, probably like this:

```
form = new FormGroup({
  supName: new FormControl(),
  ...
});
```

Now whatever value you set on the `value` attribute on this line:

```
<mat-option value="{{supName.$key}}">{{supName.compName}}</mat-option>
```

Is going to be set on the `form`'s `value` as the `supName` property.

As of now, you're setting `supName.$key` as the `value`. If you want to set `supName.compName` you can do that too.

```
<mat-option value="{{supName.compName}}">{{supName.compName}}</mat-option>
```

---

> Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1nqbih?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.ts) for your ref.

Take a look at the `onSubmit` method and what it logs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to save multiple properties for this `form control`, you can save the full `object`, as follows:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select formControlName="supName" placeholder="Company">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let supName of array">
        <mat-option [value]="supName" <!-- HERE ->>{{ supName.compName }}</mat-option>
      </ng-container>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1nqbih-vj6apm)</kbd>